# Why is the output 0 (=false)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operators, logical-operators

I'm exercising opreators in C++ and I don't understand the output of the code bellow

```
int x = 21, z = 33, y = 43;
cout << (!(z < y&& x < z) || !(x = z - y)) << endl;
```

I wrote it with the thought to be true and I understand it as "it's not the case z is less than y and x is less than z (which is false) or it's not the case x is equal to the difference of z and y (which is true)" so I expected output 1 (=true) and I'm confused that's not the case. Can you explain me where I'm making a mistake?

edit: Thanks for the answers, it's funny how I made such trivial mistakes I actually read about.

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` is comparison

Comment: rule 0 of coding: If something is complicated, split it in smaller parts until you can manage the smaller parts. Even if this expression would yield the expected result I'd never squeeze it all in one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part that you misinterpreted:

```
!(x = z - y))
```

`x = z - y` is assignment. It yields `-10` as result. `-10` is not `0`, hence negating it yields `false`.

Now, first part of the expression:

```
!(z < y&& x < z) 
!(33 < 43 && 21 < 33) 
!(true && true) 
!(true)  
false
```

Putting it together:

```
(false || false) == false
```

Answer (score 0):

This `=` is an assignment operator. It *assigns* values.
This `==` is a comparison operator. It is used to *compare* two values.

```
int value = 5, value2 = 12;
if(value == value2)
{
    // do something if value and value2 are EQUAL (which they are not)
}
```

See [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/) for more information on operators in C++.